# Electron: load and display local image successfully, but can not copy and paste the image

Tags: image, electron, protocols, paste

In electron render process:  load and display image on the app, success:

```html
<img src="file:///Users/test/1.png">
```

**The Problem: When I tried to select, copy and paste the image, failed!**

So what is the right way to resolve the problem ?

---

Some supplementary notes:
Http/https protocol is ok:

```html
<img src="http://test.com/1.png">
```

But file protocol failed:

```html
<img src="file:///Users/test/1.png">
```